# Localizations.of return null from StatelessWidget

Tags: flutter

As the title said, if the widget class is extended from `StatelessWidget`

```
Localizations.of<MaterialLocalizations>(context, MaterialLocalizations);
```

will return null any ideas?

Comment: Did you register `localizationsDelegates` https://flutter.io/tutorials/internationalization/?

Comment: Have there been any updates the last 2 yrs to that? I'm new to flutter.

Answer (score 5):

had the same problem. Theres an open [github issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/26365) in the flutter repository. Only thing that solved it for me was creating a separat widget like this:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        localizationsDelegates: [...],
        supportedLocales: ..,
        locale: ...,
        home: MyAppPage()); // separat MyAppPage instead of putting widget code with translations here
  }

// MyAppPage
class MyAppPage extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        ...
        body: Center(
            child: Text(AppTranslations.of(context).translate(...)),
```

If this is not solving your problem we maybe need to see more code :)!

Answer (score 0):

If you call it from a function out side this, it caused the problem because it can't get right context.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {}
```

You can handle this by

- transfer context if you call a function return widget
- declare language variables out side Widget build and reset them after.
- write the widget as a separate widget. 
  If these ways still don't work. Please add more details of your code.

Hope this help.