# flutter: supported language is throwing error (Localizations.of<MaterialLocalizations>(context, MaterialLocalizations) returns null)

Tags: flutter, dart, localization, flutter-widget

Every time startting my app I get the following warning in the log:

```
════════
I/flutter (22601): Warning: This application's locale, de, is not supported by all of its
I/flutter (22601): localization delegates.
I/flutter (22601): > A MaterialLocalizations delegate that supports the de locale was not found.
I/flutter (22601): See flutter.dev/tutorials/internationalization for more
I/flutter (22601): information about configuring an app's locale, supportedLocales,
I/flutter (22601): and localizationsDelegates parameters.
I/flutter (22601):
════════
```

Also, when trying to use various widgets like`AppBar` or when trying to show a dialog I can't do that because flutter throws following assert (exception):

```
No MaterialLocalizations found.
```

since

```
Localizations.of<MaterialLocalizations>(context, MaterialLocalizations) == null
```

assertion is true.

German is listed as a supported locale, and I have registered `supportedLanguages` as well as `localizationDelegates` in my `MaterialApp`. Since I use `MaterialApp` as the main root `StatelessWidget`, I don't get why this error is thrown.
I have already searched and found not much, just [this old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51094878/localizations-of-return-null-from-statelesswidget) with no real answer to it, which is the same problem. There is also a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/13617) to this problem, but it seems like not really many others have the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any future reader, I found the issue:
I didn't include the package:

```
flutter_localizations:
  sdk: flutter
```

and also didn't include the `GlobalMaterialLocalization` delegates:

```
localizationsDelegates: [
        S.delegate,
        GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
      ],
```